# How to convert a file of any type into byte array?

Tags: c#, serialization, arrays, deserialization

The file can be of any type ( png,bmp,jpeg,doc,docx,pdf) I have to convert the file into  byte array and send to server via WebRequest where it will be converted to the corresponding file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's as easy as `var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) for example... BEWARE that this loads the complete file into RAM...

Answer (score 2):

Use FileStream, you provide it the path to the file and can get the array from it.

Comment: Actually, use ybo's method. Much cleaner